# Can anyone explain this warning?

Tags: php

What is the meaning of of the warning?

```
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at offset 1 in
```

It's being triggered by this function:

```
file_put_contents($file,preg_replace('(\uid=\d+)', 'uid=' . $uid, file_get_contents($file)));
```

Namely this pattern:

```
'(\uid=\d+)'
```

It works locally, but not online, meaning it's probably my host's version of PHP. I've tried to google a work-around, but can't find anything.

Comment: that's an invalid pattern. you forgot the delimiters, e.g. `/(\uid....`.

Comment: @MarcB - `()` are in fact valid delimiters.

Comment: @Marc B: `(` and `)` are valid delimiters too AFAIK. But it prevents you from using brackets in the pattern, so it's usually not a good choice.

Comment: What are you trying to match with `\u`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: seesh, php needs to update their docs. text talks about brackets, but the example uses `{}`. go figure. thanks...

Comment: @fab As long as the parentheses are balanced, it's not a problem.

Comment: @MarcB The doc says "bracket style delimiters", meaning pairs of bracketing characters in general, not specifically square brackets.

Comment: @E_ERROR I won't flag it as duplicate, it's not the same error even if it is related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PCRE doesn't support the `\u` espace sequence.

In other words, your regex is not correct. Try something like `(uid=\d+)` instead.

As said in comments (thanks Mellamokb), here is the [source](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.differences.php).

If you want to know what is the `\u`, you can look [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html)

> \u                Titlecase next character.  Not in [ ].

Comment: +1 Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.differences.php, #5.

Comment: Worked first time! Thanks all.

Comment: @JWH You're welcome. Regex are always somewhat tricky when you're not used to them :)

Comment: @Geoffroy Yes, they are a bit fiddly! Nice when they work though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents($file,preg_replace('/uid=\d+/', 'uid=' . $uid, file_get_contents($file)));
```

Answer (score 0):

RegExp pattern should be bounded by `/` delimiters, you can also use (`#` or `~`). Moreover there is no escape sequence `\u`. You may wanna try this -

```
preg_replace('/\\uid=\d+/', 'uid=' . $uid, file_get_contents($file))
```